# onclick event not working for th tag

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I'm able to successfully do `onclick` events in my component, except when I try it on `<th>`. Why doesn't it work? I'm trying to do an onclick event on the `<th>` to do sorting of the table data.

Component

```
<aura:component controller="ProjectAndTicketListController" access="global" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.Utility}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />

    <aura:attribute name="view" type="String" default="openT" description="the tab view that is currently selected" />
    <aura:attribute name="projects" type="List" description="From TaskRay" />
    <aura:attribute name="tickets" type="List" description="The Case object" />

    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="{!v.view == 'openT' ? 'active': ''}"><a data-value="openT" onclick="{!c.handleView}">Open Tickets</a></li>
        <li class="{!v.view == 'closedT' ? 'active': ''}"><a data-value="closedT" onclick="{!c.handleView}">Closed
                Tickets</a></li>
        <li class="{!v.view == 'openP' ? 'active': ''}"><a data-value="openP" onclick="{!c.handleView}">Open Projects</a></li>
        <li class="{!v.view == 'closedP' ? 'active': ''}"><a data-value="closedP" onclick="{!c.handleView}">Closed
                Projects</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
            <table class="tg">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.view == 'openP' || v.view == 'closedP'}">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="tg-16zm" onclick="{!c.handleSort}">Project Name</th>
                        <th class="tg-16zm">Start Date</th>
                        <th class="tg-16zm">Progress</th>
                    </tr>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.projects}" var="p">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-g9rn"><a href="{!'/s/detail/' + p.Id}">{!p.Name}</a></td>
                            <td class="tg-g9rn">
                                <ui:outputDate value="{!p.TASKRAY__Project_Start__c}" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="tg-g9rn">{!p.TASKRAY__trCompletionPercentage__c}%</td>
                        </tr>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.view == 'openT' || v.view == 'closedT'}">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="tg-h4o5" onclick="{!c.handleSort}">ID</th>
                        <th class="tg-16zm">Ticket Number</th>
                        <th class="tg-16zm">Created By</th>
                        <th class="tg-16zm">Date Created</th>
                        <th class="tg-16zm">Status</th>
                    </tr>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.tickets}" var="t">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-g9rn"><a href="{!'/s/detail/' + t.Id}">{!t.CaseNumber}</a></td>
                            <td class="tg-g9rn">{!t.Subject}</td>
                            <td class="tg-g9rn">{!t.CreatedBy.Name}</td>
                            <td class="tg-g9rn">
                                <ui:outputDate value="{!t.CreatedDate}" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="tg-g9rn">{!v.view == 'openT' ? 'Open' : 'Closed'}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </aura:if>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Component Controller

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        let searchValue = helper.getSearchValue(component);
        helper.getRecords(component, searchValue);
    },
    handleView: function (component, event, helper) {
        let searchValue = helper.getSearchValue(component);
        let selectedView = event.currentTarget.dataset.value;

        component.set("v.view", selectedView);
        helper.getRecords(component, searchValue);
    },
    handleSort: function (component, event, helper) {
        console.log('onclick is happening');
    }
})
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use lightning data table which offers a rowSorting functionality if you are bumped with `<th>` onclick. Look into [THIS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleDatatableInAction)

Comment: I need a custom styled table. What I don't like about lightning data table is it's hard to style.

Comment: I tried running your code, the log seems to be appearing to me and the onclick is working. Try `alert('onclick is happening');` instead of console.log and see if the message will appear.